# Android Regex pattern Encoding UTF-8

Tags: javascript, android, json, regex, encoding

I am trying this code in android for catching (.+?) with matcher.group(1):

```
String html = doc.html().toString();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?is)caption\":\"(.+?)\",", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
if (m.find()){
     text_main = m.group(1);
}
```

it works, but not with all characters. when (.+?) contains persian characters or characters from any language except english, it doesn't work. I think patterns just support UTF-16.

so what can i do for UTF-8 characters? can i catch UTF-8 characters with this way? If i can't, so what can i do instead?

mainly I'm trying to get a string from a json object. the json code is placed in a script in a html page.

Comment: Haven't I already commented this post today? BTW, it ought to match Unicode letters.

Comment: What you mean? What i have to do?